# IF ISERROR Excel #DIV/0! while divide for 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using Excel 2011 and trying to remove those #DIV/0! errors, this is the formula

```
=IF(ISERROR((C20-C21)/C21),"-",(C20-C21)/C21)
```

It seems correct, i made it by many examples here on stackoverflow, but in my excel 2011 doesn't works ! System told me that i have a syntax error. Help needed ! Thanks

Comment: Hopefully my answer helps, but if we want to solve the syntax error you need to post the full formula because the code you posted is completely valid and can be copied and pasted into excel without error

Comment: The formula as posted should work (at least it does in my version).  However, do your regional settings use a comma `,` instead of a period `.` for the decimal symbol (like in many non-English-speaking countries)?  If so, try `=IF(ISERROR((C20-C21)/C21);"-";(C20-C21)/C21)` (with a semi-colon `;` instead of a comma `,` as the list separator).

Comment: @BrianCamire yeah ! was the exactly right problem ! the regional settings :)) thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function

```
ISERROR
```

Will return true/false based on if it finds an error.  You can wrap that in the `IF` statement like you did:

`=IF(ISERROR((C20-C21)/C21),"-",(C20-C21)/C21)`

Which actually does not have a syntax error.  That syntax error must be somewhere else in your function.  If you copy that directly into a cell you will see it works.

However,

**There is a function that does this for you already**: `IFERROR`

```
IFERROR((C20-C21)/C21),"-")
```

Comment: "That syntax error must be somewhere else in your function" yeah...i can't discover the problem but open another new sheet the function works ! thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can also write `(C20-C21)/C21` as `C20/C21-1` and consequently this formula should work for you

`=IFERROR(C20/C21-1,"-")`